# Microcontroller SDLC interface

Tags: microcontroller, rs485

I want my AVR microcontroller based device to communicate via SDLC (Synchronous Data Link Control) physical interface with another device, SDLC is RS-485 based.

The SDLC interface must have the following connections: 
1) Tx data+, 
2)Tx data-, 
3)Rx data+, 
4)Rx data-, 
5)Tx clock+, 
6)Tx clock-, 
7)Rx clock+, 
8)Rx clock-

I thought I could use RS-485 chip to provide those 8 connections, but the problem is RS-485 chips have connections 1 to 4 (Tx data+, Tx data-, Rx data+, Rx data-), so no clocks (Tx clock+, Tx clock-, etc).

Anybody know of any chip or circuit that I can use so at the end my microcontroller can communicate via SDLC on eight interface pins?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your "RS485 chip"? The ones I know are line drivers/receivers. Simply use a second one for the clock.

Comment: I take it you're bit-banging the actual SDLC framing?

Comment: SDLC is normally RS-422 based, not RS-485. Same electrical specs, but used very differently.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, thanks, that solved the question I had.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks, yes will be bit banging, actually mentioning bit banging got me to do research about it and found that combining bit banging with the full duplex RS-485 chip (MAX488) I would get the job done. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to vote an answer like other forums?

Comment: These are not answers, they're comments trying to get you to clarify your question. You can upvote them to show that you found them useful (hover your cursor near the left end of each one, click on the triangle that appears). Actual answers would appear below, and they can be both up- and down-voted. And this isn't a forum; it's a crowd-sourced information repository in question-and-answer format. You improve the site by asking good questions.

Comment: @tmoeti -- write up an actual answer for the question and I'll give you an upvote for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 full duplex RS-485 chips (e.g MAX488). One for TX, RX lines and the other chip for clocks.

Send data over through bit banging. And also use bit banging to receive and decode the data. With these implementation communication over SDLC protocol would be possible.

Obviously one need to have correct understanding of the SDLC protocol so as to be able to send right packets and decode data through bit banging.